# How to use keyboard event and timer?

Tags: c#

I want the next:
when you press spacebar - label1.Text become to "Up", after several second (random from 1 to 5) label1.Text will change to "Remove hand" and then KeyUp label1.Text will change "Down".
I know how to use KeyUp and KeyDown, but I don't understand how to use timer???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Timer timer = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                label1.Text = "Down";
                timer.Interval = 5000;//5 seconds
                timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                label1.Text = "Up";
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Remove";
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at the [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) class. Especially the Elapsed event might be of interest to you.

Comment: I've tried this.. but it didn't work. See code above.

Comment: What does not work in the code above? What did you expect and what happened (or didn't happened for that matter ;) ). You have to give us more information to work on (for you).

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //check key press args for space here

        timer.Interval = 5000;//5 seconds

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Up";
        timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Basically, the interval property is in milliseconds, this is where you specify how long you want to wait. You then add an event handler to the Elapsed event. This will fire when the specified period of time has elapsed from when you called the Start() method.

Comment: I'm not sure if explaining the code would help annayak more than just giving a complete source code example without any comments.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyDown` will keep firing if the user does not let go, so you probably need a variable to start the timer only once.

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
private bool _SpacePressed = false;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.KeyPreview = true;
  label1.Text = "Down";
  timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);    
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer1.Stop();
  label1.Text = "Remove Hand";
}

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
  base.OnKeyDown(e);
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && !_SpacePressed) {
    _SpacePressed = true;
    label1.Text = "Up";
    timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(1, 5) * 1000;
    timer1.Start();
  }
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) {
  base.OnKeyUp(e);
  if (_SpacePressed) {
    _SpacePressed = false;
    timer1.Stop();
    label1.Text = "Down";
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a variable to keep press of the key state, using the KeyPress-event might be a better choice.

Comment: @Skalli `KeyPress` will keep firing, too.

Comment: @annayak: Is it clear to you **how** this works? I'm asking because it's of more value to you if you do, in case you run into your next problems.

Comment: @LarsTech: Indeed, I've mixed up something. Sorry.